# Error: write ENOTSUP on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I tried to use cluster in Azure WebApps service but I got the error

```
Error: write ENOTSUP
```

I am attaching my source below the source is executed by web.config file.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const os = require('os');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  const cpus = os.cpus().length;

  console.log(`Forking for ${cpus} CPUs`);

  for (let i = 0; i < cpus; i++)
    cluster.fork();

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    if (code !== '0' && !worker.exitedAfterDisconnect) {
      console.log(`Worker ${worker.id} crashed. Starting a new worker...`);
      cluster.fork();
    }
  });

  process.on('SIGUSR2', () => {
    const workers = Object.values(cluster.workers);

    const restartWorker = (workerIndex) => {
      const worker = workers[workerIndex];
      if (!worker)
        return;

      worker.on('exit', () => {
        if (!worker.exitedAfterDisconnect)
          return;
        console.log(`Exited process ${worker.process.pid}`);
        cluster.fork().on('listening', () => {
          restartWorker(workerIndex + 1);
        });
      });

      worker.disconnect();

    };

    restartWorker(0);
  });

} else {
  require('./bin/www');
}
```

Does Azure support cluster in WebApps?
If not what are the options?

Thanks, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Cluster is not supported on Azure Web Apps as it doesn't support use of named pipes. See this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/419

Your option would be to use either **Azure Cloud Services** or **Azure Virtual Machines**.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem and during research I have found that if you want to use clustering in your node app you can't use native node cluster. However, if your machine have more than one CPU core and you want to make balancing you can add this line in you web.config file.

```
 <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" devErrorsEnabled="true" nodeProcessCountPerApplication="0" />
```

> - nodeProcessCountPerApplication.
>
>   This setting controls the number of node processes that are launched
>     per IIS application. The default value is 1. You can launch as many
>     node.exes as your VM vCPU count by setting this to 0. The recommended
>     value is 0 for most applications so you can use all of the vCPUs on
>     your machine. Node.exe is single-threaded so one node.exe consumes a
>     maximum of 1 vCPU. To get maximum performance out of your node
>     application, you want to use all vCPUs

Read this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide)

After setting this value and redeploying your app (it's need some time to refresh) your can check your "Process explorer" by going to you App Service -> Monitor section -> Process explorer. Here you can find current number of cores your App Service use.